# Opening a .msg file in Outlook and saving it as a Draft

Tags: outlook, directx

I work on a web-application that can produce mails that the user can open in Outlook and then e.g send or save it to Drafts. Until recently, we were using DirectX, which directly interacted with Outlook, meaning it directly created a new mail for the user and filled in certain things in Outlook (such as recipient, body and so on).

We are now moving away from DirectX and our current solution for imitating the behaviour described above is that user downloads a .msg file that is then being automatically opened in Outlook.

The behavour of these two implementations is nearly the same, however, there is one difference that causes problems: When using DirectX, saving the mail in Outlook will cause it to be saved under "Drafts". When using the File-Download, saving the mail in Outlook will update the downloaded .msg file. Is there a way to make it so that even when using a File-Download the mail is saved to "Drafts" when the Save-Button is pressed in Outlook? Alternatively is there an easy solution for manually saving the opened mail to "Drafts" (with as few clicks as possible) ?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is produce an EML file instead of MSG (don't forget to set `X-Unsent: 1` MIME header), but it gets saved in the Inbox folder, not Drafts.